# Chrome refusing to cache localhost

Tags: http, google-chrome, caching, http-caching

I am writing a server which detects `If-Modified-Since` header values and responds with `304` as appropriate. The problem is, I can't get Chrome to send an `If-Modified-Since` header without resorting to something like [Rest Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon), but I want to test real-world conditions, not requests constructed to my liking.

I am requesting `http://localhost:3000/style.css` from Chrome. The server responds with `Expires` and `Last-Modified` headers as such:

[image: Request and response headers.]

When I request again, I always get a `200 OK` response with the same values for `Expires` and `Last-Modified` (I am purposely sending the same values). Chrome never sends the request with an `If-Modified-Since` header. I am able to get the `304 Not Modified` response from my server using Rest Console, but I need to know how to get Chrome to send `If-Modified-Since` on its own. I have tried `Cahce-Control: max-age=...` but to no avail. And yes, I have checked that cache is not disabled in the developer tools:

[image: Cache is enabled.]

By this point I hope the question is apparent: why isn't Chrome sending `If-Modified-Since` headers? As a bonus question: what else should I check server-side to determine if it is appropriate to respond with `304 Not Modified`?

Comment: I'm having a same issue just now. Can you try with this date format: (PHP) `header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 3600 * 24 * 365));` someone said that Chrome is very picky on  correct date format. But to me which I pasted didn't work either. With Firefox it works just fine though.